# Solr: Document size inexplicably large

Tags: solr

I updated to Solr 8.4.0 (from 6.x) on a test server and reindexed (this is an index of a complicated Moodle system, mainly lots of very small documents). It worked initially, but later ran out of disk space so I deleted everything and tried indexing a smaller subset of the data, but it still ran out of disk space.

Looking at the segment info chart, the first segment seems reasonable:

Segment _2a1u:
#docs: 603,564
#dels: 1
size: 5,275,671,226 bytes
age: 2020-11-25T22:10:05.023Z
source: merge

That's 8,740 bytes per document - a little high but not too bad.

Segment _28ow:
#docs: 241,082
#dels: 31
size: 5,251,034,504 bytes
age: 2020-11-25T18:33:59.636Z
source: merge

21,781 bytes per document

Segment _2ajc:
#docs: 50,159
#dels: 1
size: 5,222,429,424 bytes
age: 2020-11-25T23:29:35.391Z
source: merge

104,117 bytes per document!

And it gets worse, looking at the small segments near the end:

Segment _2bff:
#docs: 2
#dels: 0
size:23,605,447 bytes
age: 2020-11-26T01:36:02.130Z
source: flush

None of our search documents will have anywhere near that much text.

On our production Solr 6.6 server, which has similar but slightly larger data (some of it gets replaced with short placeholder text in the test server for privacy reasons) the large 5GB-ish segments contain between 1.8 million and 5 million documents.

Does anyone know what could have gone wrong here? We are using Solr Cell/Tika and I'm wondering if somehow it started storing the whole files instead of just the extracted text?

Comment: I'm not sure if Luke can open a segment file directly, but I'd start there. Luke is included with the standard Lucene binary distribution: https://lucene.apache.org/core/downloads.html - but your guess about a newer version of Tika including more information could be a correct assumption. Have you tried looking at the documents included in `_2bff` to see which fields and content they contain?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Gives me something to try next. I also checked the solrconfig.xml between the two versions and found that the Solr Cell config in the new one is missing the line <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str> which certainly seems like it might be using more space... I'll correct that and retry as a first step.

Comment: That would certainly make a difference, yes. In many formats (such as PDF files) the metadata can contain vector graphs, thumbnails, color profilers, etc.

Comment: I tried Luke, but not only does it not let you open a single segment file, it also doesn't let you see what documents are in what segment - nor does anything else that I could find. (I've wanted to know that before for different reasons, it's annoying that there's no easy way to display it.) Eventually by a binary-search type process (indexing smaller chunks), I managed to narrow down the single document that has the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that a 10MB English language PowerPoint file being indexed, with mostly pictures and only about 50 words of text in the whole thing, is indexed (with metadata turned off) as nearly half a million terms most of which are Chinese characters. Presumably, Tika has incorrectly extracted some of the binary content of the PowerPoint file as if it were text.

I was only able to find this by reducing the index by trial and error until there are only a handful of documents in it (3 documents but using 13MB disk space), then Luke 'Overview' tab let me see that one field (called solr_filecontent in my schema) which contains the indexed Tika results has 451,029 terms. Then, clicking 'Show top terms' shows a bunch of Chinese characters.

I am not sure if there is a less laborious way than trial and error to find this problem, e.g. if there's any way to find documents that have a large number of terms associated. (Obviously, it could be a very large PDF or something that legitimately has that many terms, but in this case, it isn't.) This would be useful as even if there are only a few such instances across our system, they could contribute quite a lot to overall index size.

As for resolving the problem:

1 - I could hack something to stop it indexing this individual document (which is used repeatedly in our test data otherwise I probably wouldn't have noticed) but presumably the problem may occur in other cases as well.

2 - I considered excluding the terms in some way but we do have a small proportion of content in various languages, including Chinese, in our index so even if there is a way to configure it to only use ASCII text or something, this wouldn't help.

3 - My next step was to try different versions to see what happens with the same file, in case it is a bug in specific Tika versions. However, I've tested with a range of Solr versions - 6.6.2, 8.4.0, 8.6.3, and 8.7.0 - and the same behaviour occurs on all of them.

So my conclusion from all this is that:

- Contrary to my intitial assumption that this was related to the version upgrade, it isn't actually worse now than it was in the older Solr version.
- In order to get this working now I will probably have to do a hack to stop it indexing that specific PowerPoint file (which occurs frequently on our test dataset). Presumably the real dataset wouldn't have too many files like that otherwise it would already have run out of disk space there...

Comment: Just to note, it turns out this problem occurs only when you upload the file in one of the two different ways shown in the documentation. I have filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-15039 about it.